# How to add date-time arguments to django URL tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to get this URL in my template.

```
    path('show_date/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:date>/',show_date,name='show_date'),
```

My template

```
    <a href="{%url 'diary:show_date'{{date|date:'Y'}} {{date|date:'m'}} {{date|date:'j'}} 
%}">{{date}}</a>
```

returns this error

```
Could not parse some characters: 'diary:show_date'|{{date||date:'Y'}}
```

Please help me fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't add the double braces when you use a filter on a variable in a tag, you can use the filters without them

```
<a href="{% url 'show_date' date|date:'Y' date|date:'m' date|date:'j' %}">{{ date }}</a>
```